# transform sql view output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to format a sql output of 1 column to 3 columns?

For eg. My current output is:

```
Column1
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
```

here is how I want the output to be:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
   1       2       3
   4       5       6
   7       8       9
```

Comment: what logic you are using to put a certain value in a certain column ???

Comment: @M.Ali Row2 will go to Column2,Row1 and Row3 will go to Column3,Row1 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with modulus division and the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Column1) RN
              FROM Table1)
     ,cte2 AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RN%3 ORDER BY Column1) RN2                          
               FROM cte)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN RN%3 = 1 THEN column1 END) Col1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN%3 = 2 THEN column1 END) Col2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN%3 = 0 THEN column1 END) Col3
      ,RN2 
FROM cte2
GROUP BY RN2
```

Example: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2620a/2/0)

Comment: Values in my question above (1 through 9) are just examples. I have no idea what the values would be. It could be a though z or it could be alpha-numeric values.

Comment: I get this error:
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'JRD1123' to data type int.

Comment: @user793468 Yes, a non-numeric field can't be divided, had to add the row number in a separate step.  See updated example with animals.

Comment: What is I have two columns? and I want to display like:
1,a 2,b 3,c...
here a,b,c... would be values from second column

Comment: @user793468 It would be easiest to concatenate the two columns together in the first step, ie:  `SELECT col1 +','+ col2 AS NewCol, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1, col2) RN` in the top line.  Then reference NewCol instead of col1 later.

Comment: I noticed something, if the output is just two rows(Initial Output) Then the transformed output looks like this:
Col1: Empty
Col2: Empty
Col3: Shows two records

Comment: Strange. Could it be because I have a WHERE clause before last Group By?